# R seems to multiply my data by -1

Tags: r

Every time I try to upload a database into R (the file is in .xls, .csv or .txt) it transforms it and put a negative sign in front of every entry of my file. I do not really understand why. Could someone help me?

```
> data<-- read.table("C:\\Users\\Géraldine\\Documents\\R\\RS_simplified.txt", header = TRUE, sep="\t")
> data
    Year   Index       r Indexcorr   rcorr
1  -1957 -100.00  0.0000   -100.00  0.0000
2  -1958  -92.16  0.0784    -89.23  0.1077
3  -1959 -123.39 -0.3389   -125.85 -0.4103
4  -1960 -125.55 -0.0175   -121.48  0.0347
5  -1961 -135.18 -0.0767   -135.28 -0.1136
6  -1962 -139.47 -0.0318   -139.16 -0.0286
7  -1963 -140.72 -0.0089   -140.61 -0.0104
8  -1964 -141.97 -0.0089   -142.07 -0.0104
9  -1965 -169.44 -0.1935   -169.27 -0.1915
10 -1966 -189.45 -0.1181   -168.85  0.0025
11 -1967 -202.26 -0.0676   -180.07 -0.0665
12 -1968 -232.17 -0.1479   -218.37 -0.2127
13 -1969 -239.08 -0.0298   -220.90 -0.0116
14 -1970 -217.57  0.0900   -192.44  0.1288
15 -1971 -256.25 -0.1778   -224.01 -0.1640
16 -1972 -307.22 -0.1989   -293.22 -0.3089
17 -1973 -402.77 -0.3110   -354.73 -0.2098
18 -1974 -363.61  0.0972   -316.75  0.1071
19 -1975 -290.66  0.2006   -250.89  0.2079
20 -1976 -261.31  0.1010   -223.75  0.1082
21 -1977 -260.68  0.0024   -224.25 -0.0022
22 -1978 -298.69 -0.1458   -256.07 -0.1419
23 -1979 -322.86 -0.0809   -272.49 -0.0641
24 -1980 -324.22 -0.0042   -270.26  0.0082
25 -1981 -283.94  0.1243   -238.83  0.1163
26 -1982 -237.56  0.1634   -197.49  0.1731
27 -1983 -243.21 -0.0238   -202.62 -0.0260
28 -1984 -247.40 -0.0172   -212.10 -0.0468
29 -1985 -271.17 -0.0961   -230.80 -0.0882
30 -1986 -342.76 -0.2640   -291.75 -0.2640
31 -1987 -471.38 -0.3753   -406.86 -0.3946
32 -1988 -575.35 -0.2206   -492.07 -0.2094
33 -1989 -713.58 -0.2403   -627.57 -0.2754
34 -1990 -757.79 -0.0620   -666.68 -0.0623
35 -1991 -513.24  0.3227   -420.25  0.3696
36 -1992 -462.02  0.0998   -374.26  0.1095
37 -1993 -392.01  0.1515   -319.51  0.1463
38 -1994 -389.41  0.0066   -323.27 -0.0118
39 -1995 -394.58 -0.0133   -328.17 -0.0152
40 -1996 -392.66  0.0049   -324.78  0.0103
41 -1997 -392.60  0.0002   -332.02 -0.0223
42 -1998 -403.65 -0.0282   -344.60 -0.0379
43 -1999 -424.54 -0.0517   -364.60 -0.0580
44 -2000 -411.94  0.0297   -361.28  0.0091
45 -2001 -387.26  0.0599   -342.86  0.0510
46 -2002 -416.88 -0.0765   -369.08 -0.0765
47 -2003 -466.69 -0.1195   -405.40 -0.0984
48 -2004 -518.74 -0.1115   -456.07 -0.1250
49 -2005 -530.76 -0.0232   -479.76 -0.0519
50 -2006 -588.51 -0.1088   -557.62 -0.1623
51 -2007 -723.27 -0.2290   -699.91 -0.2552
```

Thank you very much for your concern.

Géraldine

Comment: Could you show a few lines of your input file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you write

```
> data<-- read.table("C:\\Users\\....)
```

you are really writing

```
> data <- - read.table("C:\\Users\\....)
```

or equivalently

```
> data <- (-1) * read.table("C:\\Users\\....)
```

Just remove the second dash, and your data will not be multiplied by -1.  R simply did what you told it to.

Comment: and if your original intent was to use `<<-` then you shouldn't use that either. Always prefer `<-` unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: You are welcome. It is common practice to accept a useful and suitable answer which you (who asked the question) can do by clicking on the 'tick mark'.