# Read.csv makes everything negative

Tags: r, csv, read.table, read.csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R seems to multiply my data by -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182735/r-seems-to-multiply-my-data-by-1)

I have a simple csv file. Looks like this

x y
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 3

I created it in MS Excel, saved as csv etc.

I read it using this command

ttest<--read.csv("ttest.csv", header = TRUE)

The resulting data looks like this

x y 
-1 -2
-1 -3
-2 -1
-2 -3

I've opened the original csv file in a text editor and it looks like it should

Comment: I answered that same question / problem before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that your command:

```
ttest<--read.csv("ttest.csv", header = TRUE)
```

... has an extra dash after the `<-` and R is interpreting this as a negative sign, and thus negating any numbers that it reads before it loads the data into `ttest`.

In addition, there may be some confusion between `read.csv()`, which is for reading comma-separated value files and `read.table()`, which will read files like:

```
x y 
1 2 
1 3 
2 1 
2 3
```

... which is rather more what I think your file might have looked like originally.