# numeric values have been multiplied by -1

Tags: r, csv

I supplied a csv file to my students for an assignment.  When I read the file using `read.csv("Bob.csv")` using Rstudio, the file is read correctly.  When a student reads the exact same file, all the numeric values have values as if they were multiplied by -1.  Thus, when the csv file has a value of .289 I read it as into R as .289.  For my student, the file is read into R as -.289.

So far, we verified that the csv file on the student's computer is correct (the number is .289). We verified that she is reading the correct file. We have verified that she consistently gets the numbers to be as if they had multiplied by -1 (-.289). We verified that the number is wrong in the file created by the read.csv command.

This issue shows up in every numeric value in the file (all the values are numeric).

We cleaned her registry. We rebooted. We cleared her R environment.

Comment: See if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407600/read-csv-makes-everything-negative

Comment: can you post the file? have you tried a different file, freshly created? May we see your code for ingest? You should work to extend your diagnosis from a single file.

Comment: Can you give us her line? She likely has written `<--` instead of `<-`.

Comment: @Pascal, it's already linked as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure how much it matters as long as the dupe-cluster is clearly identified?  (I guess maybe there's a meta-stack-overflow discussion of this somewhere ...)

Comment: Ouistiti was correct the student had used two dashes  <--